# Help on induction, couldn't make both side the same value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial, recursion

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1} $$
Induction g(n+1)=f(n+1)+g(n) sub n+1
(1)$$(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)(p+1)+\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1}(p+1) $$
(2)
$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+1+p)} {p+1}(p+1)$$
make (1)=(2)
$$(n+p)!(p+1)+(n+p)!=(n+1+p)! $$

I then couldnt make the R.H.S==L.H.S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)~=~\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1} $$

First of all this given sum can be simplified by using factorials

$$\frac{(n+p)!}{(n-1)!}~=~n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)$$

In general the term

$$(x,n)~=~x^{\overline{n}}~=~\frac{(x+n+1)!}{(x+1)!}$$
is called Pochhammer symbol or rising factorial.
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+p-1)!}{(k-1)!}~&=~\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1}\\~&=~\frac{(n+p)!}{(n-1)!(p+1)}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(k+p-1)!}{(k-1)!}~&=~\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+p+1)} {p+1}\\~&=~\frac{(n+p+1)!}{n!(p+1)}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(k+p-1)!}{(k-1)!}~=~&\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+p-1)!}{(k-1)!}~+~\frac{(n+p)}{n!}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+p-1)!}{(k-1)!}~+~\frac{(n+p)!}{n!}~&=~\frac{(n+p)!}{(n-1)!(p+1)}~+~\frac{(n+p)!}{n!}\\&=~\frac{n(n+p)!+(p+1)(n+p)!}{n!(p+1)}\\&=~\frac{(n+p+1)(n+p)!}{n!(p+1)}\\&=~\frac{(n+p+1)!}{n!(p+1)}\end{align}$$

Maybe this slightly different approach to your problem can help you to get further.

Comment: Do u mind explaining why when u multiply n! to (n+p)! why it renders to n(n+p)!

Comment: I never multiplied $(n+p)!$ ny $n!$. I used the fact that $n!=n(n-1)!$. While the final denominator of the fraction is $n!(p+1)$ I have to multiply the first fraction by $\frac{n}{n}$ and the second one by $\frac{p+1}{p+1}$.

Comment: Sry for asking a stupid question, but how did u get rid (n-1)! from the denominator and render it to n!(p+1)?

Comment: There is no problem in further asking :) $\Big |$$\frac{(n+p)!}{(n-1)!(p+1)}\frac{n}{n}~=~\frac{n(n+p)!}{n(n-1)!(p+1)}$ which is equal to $\frac{n(n+p)!}{n!(p+1)}$ by the functional equation of the factorial $n!~=~n(n-1)!$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or why you are writing 1).

Just do the following.

Assuming that $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)...(k+p-1)= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)} {p+1}$

Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k(k+1)...(k+p-1) = [\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)...(k+p-1)]+ (n+1)((n+1)+1)...((n+1)+p-1)$

$= \frac{n(n+1)...(n+p)} {p+1} + (n+1)(n+2)....(n+p-1)(n+p)$

$= [(n+1)(n+2).....(n+p)](\frac n{p+1} + 1)$

$=[(n+1)(n+2).....(n+p)](\frac n{p+1} + \frac{p+1}{p+1})$

$=[(n+1)(n+2).....(n+p)](\frac {n+p + 1}{p+1})$

$=\frac {(n+1).....(n+1 + p)}{p+1}$