# Generalization of $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}2$

Tags: number-theory

During the course of another math.se question 
([What's the probability of completing the illustrated "binomial walk" without ever visiting a node above the baseline?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860403/)),
the following generalization of $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}2$ tangentially (not directly related to that discussion) came up. Moreover, it also satisfies several "magic formulas" shown below (but not posted earlier) that suggested to me maybe it's already some well-known "thing" (i.e., "somebody's polynomial" or something). If so, anybody know what it's called, and can point me to a more complete development? Here's the definition, and then those formulas that follow from it...

Define
$$
\left.
  \begin{array}{cclcl}
  H^1_n & = &                    &   & 1 \mbox{ for all $n$} \\
  H^2_n & = & \sum_{i=1}^n H^1_i & = & n \\
  H^3_n & = & \sum_{i=1}^n H^2_i & = & \frac{n(n+1)}{2!} \mbox{ (the usual)}\\
  H^4_n & = & \sum_{i=1}^n H^3_i & \stackrel{?}{=} &
              \underbrace{an^3+bn^2+cn}_{
              \mbox{solve for $a,b,c$...}} \\
        &   &   & = & \frac{1}{6}n^3 + \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{3}n \\
        &   &   & = & \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3!} \\
  \end{array}\right\}
    \begin{array}{r}
         i.e., H^m_n \stackrel{\mbox{def}}{=}
         \sum_{i=1}^n H^{m-1}_i, \mbox{with } H^1_n=1.\\
         \mbox{And since } H^m_{n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} H^{m-1}_i,\\
         \mbox{note that } H^m_n=H^m_{n-1}+H^{m-1}_n \mbox{ too.}
         \end{array}
$$

And by examination we infer the general expression
  $\begin{array}{ccl}
  H^m_n & = & \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{m-1} (n+k-1) \\
        & = & \frac{(n+m-2)!}{(m-1)!(n-1)!} \\
        &   & \mbox{which simplifies to} \\
        & = & \binom{n+m-2}{m-1} = \binom{n+m-2}{n-1} \\
  \end{array}$
And also note that $H^m_n=H^n_m$.

The two "magic formulas" that I numerically tested beyond any reasonable doubt (but haven't been able to derive) are,
$$H^{m+2}_m - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} kH^{m+1-k}_m = m \mbox{, for any } m$$
and
$$\frac{1}{m}H^{m+2}_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m kH^{m+1-k}_m
        = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k(k+1)H^{m-k}_{m-1}$$
But note that the more general progression suggested by the second formula
fails.

** **Edit** **
-------------------
Re @mrtaurho's remark about verification, I numerically generated the table illustrated below, and had the computer compare those directly-calculated values against the binomial coefficient expression. Everything's copacetic (and the computer checked many, many more values than illustrated on the table)...
$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 n&H^1_n&H^2_n&H^3_n&H^4_n&H^5_n&H^6_n&H^7_n&H^8_n&
H^9_n&H^{10}_n&H^{11}_n&H^{12}_n \\
 1&{\bf 1}&1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
 2&1&{\bf 2} & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12 \\
 3&1&3 &{\bf 6}& 10& 15& 21& 28& 36& 45& 55& 66& 78 \\
 4&1&4 & 10&{\bf 20}& 35& 56& 84&120&165&220&286&364 \\
 5&1&5 & 15& 35&{\bf 70}&126&210&330&495&715&1001&1365 \\
 6&1&6 & 21& 56&126&{\bf 252}&462&792&1287&2002&3003&4368 \\
 7&1&7 & 28& 84&210&462&{\bf 924}&1716&3003&5005&8008&12376 \\
 8&1&8 & 36&120&330&792&1716&{\bf 3432}&6435&11440&19448&31824 \\
 9&1&9 & 45&165&495&1287&3003&6435&{\bf 12870}&24310&43758&75582 \\
10&1&10& 55&220&715&2002&5005&11440&24310&{\bf 48620}&92378&167960 \\
11&1&11& 66&286&1001&3003&8008&19448&43758&92378&{\bf 184756}&352716 \\
12&1&12& 78&364&1365&4368&12376&31824&75582&167960&352716&{\bf 705432}\\
13&1&13& 91&455&1820&6188&18564&50388&125970&293930&646646&1352078\\
14&1&14&105&560&2380&8568&27132&77520&203490&497420&1144066&2496144\\
15&1&15&120&680&3060&11628&38760&116280&319770&817190&1961256&4457400\\
16&1&16&136&816&3876&15504&54264&170544&490314&1307504&3268760&7726160\\
\end{array}$

Comment: Did you tried to use Faulhaber's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to verify your general expression?

Comment: @mrtaurho No, I wasn't aware of Faulhaber's formula, but looking at that wikipedia page, I'm not seeing how it applies. As far as I can tell, $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ doesn't seem related. How do you think it's applicable?

Comment: Oh, I have mistaken one formula. I am sorry. After I saw your expressions for $H_n^3$ and $H_n^4$ I did not realized that the one factor in you product for $H_n^4$ is $(n+2)$ and *not* as I assumed $(2n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known fact, called the Hockey stick identity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: Thanks, Yves. That indeed seems closely related, and I wasn't aware of it. But note that their combinatorial proof construction $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ is "one off", so to speak, from $H^m_n=\binom{n+m-2}{m-1}$. So, e.g., that means the $H^m_n=H^n_m$ symmetry is lost (as illustrated in the "stars and bars" link from that page). And maybe more fundamentally, these binomial coefficients are merely the "answer". It's that generating-function-like approach/definition of $H^m_n$ which gives rise to that answer which would be the underlying interesting "thing". At least that's what I've been thinking.

Comment: @JohnForkosh: I understand your frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I really tried to play around with your two "magic formulas" but I did not found anything useful. Nevertheless I can prove your explicit formula for $H^m_n$ using a proof I did on a different post (which you can find here : [Help on induction, couldn't make both side the same value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858727/help-on-induction-couldnt-make-both-side-the-same-value/2858757#2858757)). The relation there is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)~\cdots (k+p-1)~=~ \frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+p)}{p+1}$$

which I will use later on. First of all we write $H_n^{m+1}$ in terms of $H_n^m$ with the equation you defined

$$H^{m+1}_n~=~\sum_{k=1}^n H_k^m $$

Now using your derived indentity

$$H_n^m~=~\binom{n+m-2}{m-1}~~\text{and respectively}~~H_n^{m+1}~=~\binom{n+m-1}{m}$$

we obtain

$$\begin{align} 
H^{m+1}_n~&=~\sum_{k=1}^n H_k^m\\
\binom{n+m-1}{m}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+m-2}{m-1}\\
\frac{(n+m-1)!}{(n-1)!~m!}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+m-2)!}{(k-1)!~(m-1)!}\\
\frac{(n+m-1)!}{(n-1)!~m}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+m-2)!}{(k-1)!}\\
\frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+m-1)}{m}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)~\cdots (k+m-2)
\end{align}$$

which equals my given equation by setting $m=p+1$.

Maybe you can go further from there on but atleast you got a proof as a verification for your solution by examination.

---

My try on the first "magic formula"

$$\begin{align}
H_m^{m+2}-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k H_m^{m-k+1}~&=~m\\
H_m^{m+2}-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k H_m^{m-k+1}+mH_m^{1}-mH_m^{1}~&=~m\\
H_m^{m+2}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} k H_m^{m-k+1}+mH_m^1~&=~m\\
H_m^{m+2}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} k H_m^{m-k+1}+m\cdot (1)~&=~m\\
H_m^{m+2}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^{m} k H_m^{m-k+1}\\
\sum_{k=1}^m H_k^{m+1}~&=~\sum_{k=1}^{m} k H_m^{m-k+1}
\end{align}$$

so therefore I guess it should be somehow possible to show

$$H_k^{m+1}~=~k H_m^{m-k+1}$$

But till now it leads me to nowhere

Comment: Thanks @mrtaurho. Actually I'd algebraically derived the binomial coefficient $H^m_n=\binom{n+m-2}{n-1}$, but just didn't bother displaying the algebra. And I apparently didn't make it clear that it had already been derived.  The numerical tests at the bottom were merely a double-check confirmation. It's only the "magic formulas" I couldn't derive. As for "usefulness", that's from my earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860403/ where the $H^m_n$'s appear in an iterative definition of something else. And that other thing simplified nicely only if those magic formulas hold.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess from now one you can be quite sure that this binomial coefficient is right. I tried some different ways, only concerning the first formula, involving some kind of induction and by taking advantage of the definitions but it always ended in some very strange binomial coefficients together with weird sums. For me the main problem which occurs is the extra $k$-factor infront of the $H_m^{m+1-k}$. I just looked over your first question and I am not sure how exactly you derived it there. Could you maybe add it to this question since you are asking here for these "magic formulas"?

Comment: Sorry, "..how exactly you derived it there"? What "it" are we referring to? If you're referring to that original product form for $H^m_n$, then I mis-spoke in the preceding comment -- I solved three equations in three unknowns to get the general form for $H^4_n$, and then inferred $H^{m>4}_n$ without algebraic proof (but with lots of numerical verification). And from there, the simplification from products to factorials to binomial coefficients was pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am sorry. My comment had ran out of characters. I was speaking about your first "magic formula". I do not exactly understand what you have done there, in your first post, to get this special relation. I would appreciate if you could add the process you have gone through to end up with this formula to this post. Or, if you do not mind, just explain it to me further than in your original question. Hence I am quite fascinated by this formula aswell I will work on it a while. Maybe I can find something useful, who knows.

Comment: Oh, right. I mentioned that above -- for both formulas. I **>>did<<** absolutely nothing. Rather, it was that other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860403/  where I noticed that I **>>needed<<** those formulas to be true (or else the stuff that I felt should simplify wouldn't simplify). So I **>>assumed<<** them true, and just did numerous numerical tests (for more values than you can shake a stick at). Then I indeed tried to prove them, but got absolutely nowhere (and it wasn't "nowhere fast", but "nowhere very slowly":)

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for the clarification. I tried an interesting way of substitution and reshaping and ended up in the need to varify that $H_k^{m+1}=kH_m^{m-k+1}$. I guess I did not made any mistake up to this point but I cannot guarantee it. Maybe you will have more luck solving this equation. If I can show something I will let you know.

Comment: By the way, note that my question above doesn't actually ask for a proof of those "magic formulas". I just mention them as a further interesting feature of $H^m_n$, further illustrating why I think it may be some well-known "thing". The actual question is merely to identify the already-named-and-studied thing I'm calling $H^m_n$ here. If somebody does that for us, I'm pretty sure you'll find everything about it that you could possibly want to know (and then some), proofs and all.

Comment: I know, but hence I was dealing a lot with induction and therefore with sums in the last few days I was motivated to try it at least. And this problem, these $magic formulas$ reminded me of the kind of problems I was dealing with before. I can understand why you wanted to mention this interesting fact about these special sums - it is quite beautiful somehow.